# Solve PHP4 to PHP5 ugrade error

Tags: php, php4

I have a client who have recently upgraded to PHP5. he have an error that says

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLONE, expecting T_STRING in ms/kernel/object.php on line 528
```

I am looking at the code but can't figure out why this is happening. Can any one please help me?

Comment: Care to share the code with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide code, I can only guess that you have classes using the now reserved keyword `clone` (from `T_CLONE`).

If you simply replace all instances of `clone` with `aclone` or `clone1` or something, you'll be fine, albeit a very hacky solution. It's a key indicator that whatever library it is you're using was written specifically for PHP4 and has not been upgraded for 5.